# I'm trying to predict time series with a Transformer model, but the results come out as a straight line

Tags: python

Below is the prediction code in my Google Colab environment.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import timedelta
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, LayerNormalization, MultiHeadAttention
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError, MeanAbsoluteError

# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('/content/data.csv')
data['Timestamp (KST)'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp (KST)'])
data.set_index('Timestamp (KST)', inplace=True)

# Load the actual data
actual_data = pd.read_csv('/content/actual_data.csv')
actual_data['Timestamp (KST)'] = pd.to_datetime(actual_data['Timestamp (KST)'])
actual_data.set_index('Timestamp (KST)', inplace=True)

# Select specific day for actual values
specific_day = '2024-11-02'
actual_values = actual_data.loc[specific_day, 'Motion Detected'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Extract the 'Motion Detected' column for training
training_data = data['Motion Detected'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
training_data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(training_data)

# Function to create sequences for training
def create_sequences(data, seq_length):
    sequences = []
    targets = []
    for i in range(len(data)-seq_length):
        seq = data[i:i+seq_length]
        target = data[i+seq_length:i+seq_length+1]
        sequences.append(seq)
        targets.append(target)
    return np.array(sequences), np.array(targets)

# Define Transformer model
def build_transformer_model(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Multi-head self-attention
    attention_output = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=4, key_dim=input_shape[1])(inputs, inputs)
    # Skip connection and layer normalization
    attention_output = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs + attention_output)
    # Feed-forward neural network
    outputs = Dense(64, activation='relu')(attention_output)
    outputs = Dropout(0.65)(outputs)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation='linear')(outputs)  # Output shape is set to 1 and linear activation function is used
    # Model
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

# Build and compile the Transformer model
sequence_length = 24  # Sequence length used during training
transformer_model = build_transformer_model(input_shape=(sequence_length, 1))
transformer_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=MeanSquaredError(), metrics=[MeanAbsoluteError()])

# Generate sequences for training
X_transformer, y_transformer = create_sequences(training_data_normalized, sequence_length)
X_transformer = X_transformer.reshape((X_transformer.shape[0], sequence_length, 1))

# Train the Transformer model
transformer_model.fit(X_transformer, y_transformer, epochs=10, batch_size=72, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

# Generate predictions for the next 24 hours
future_steps = 24
future_predictions_normalized = []

# Use the last sequence from the actual data as the initial input for predictions
current_sequence = training_data_normalized[-sequence_length:].reshape(-1)  # Flatten the sequence

for i in range(future_steps):
    # Reshape the sequence to match the input shape of the model
    current_sequence_reshaped = current_sequence[-sequence_length:].reshape((1, sequence_length, 1))

    # Make a prediction
    prediction = transformer_model.predict(current_sequence_reshaped)[0, 0]

    # Append the prediction to the list of future predictions
    future_predictions_normalized.append(prediction)

    # Update the current sequence by adding the prediction
    current_sequence = np.append(current_sequence, prediction)

# Inverse transform the normalized predictions to get the actual values
future_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(np.array(future_predictions_normalized).reshape(-1, 1))

# Generate timestamps for the future predictions (hourly time points for the next day)
last_timestamp = data.index[-1]
future_timestamps = [last_timestamp + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(1, future_steps + 1)]

# Format x-axis to display time as '00:00:00'
formatted_timestamps = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for time in future_timestamps]

# Set the figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))

# Plot the actual values as a line
plt.plot(formatted_timestamps, actual_values, label=f'Actual Values ({specific_day})', linestyle='dashed', color='green')

# Plot the predicted values as a line
plt.plot(formatted_timestamps, future_predictions, label='Predicted Values', linestyle='solid', color='blue')

# Scatter plot for actual values
for i, txt in enumerate(actual_values):
    plt.scatter(formatted_timestamps[i], txt, color='green', marker='o')
    plt.annotate(f'{int(txt[0])}', (formatted_timestamps[i], txt[0]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0, 10), ha='center')

# Scatter plot for predicted values
for i, txt in enumerate(future_predictions):
    plt.scatter(formatted_timestamps[i], txt, color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.annotate(f'{int(txt[0])}', (formatted_timestamps[i], txt[0]), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0, 10), ha='center')

plt.xlabel('Time (KST)')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
plt.ylabel('Motion Detected')
plt.title(f'Hourly Motion Detected Prediction for the Next 24 Hours ({specific_day})')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Below are the prediction results. Even if I keep modifying it, the prediction result comes out with the same value. What's the problem?

[image]

And below is my training data structure. Motion Detected is the number of motion detections and has a value between 0 and 100.

[image]